# Mongodump with authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1

Tags: mongodb, docker, sasl, sasl-scram

I have following [mongo docker image](https://medium.com/@pablo_ezequiel/creating-a-docker-image-with-mongodb-4c8aa3f828f2):

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-10gen
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["--port 27017", "--smallfiles"]
ENTRYPOINT usr/bin/mongod
```

After launching container and attaching to it using bash I try to dump remote db with following command.

```
mongodump --host *.*.*.* -port 27017 -u user -p pass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1 --out /tmp/backup/mongodump.json
```

I get exception:

```
connected to: *.*.*.*:27017
assertion: 2 SASL authentication support not compiled into client library.
```

Should I add some libraries into my image?

Comment: mongodb-10gen? Is there any reason to install such archaic package? SCRAM-SHA-1 was introduced in v3.0. IIRC the latest mongodb-10gen was 2.4.

Comment: It helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Dockerfile to install [latest Mongo version](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), since `SCRAM-SHA-1` was introduced in v3.0

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https -y
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.2 mongodb-org-server=3.6.2 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.2 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.2 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.2
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["--port 27017", "--smallfiles"]
ENTRYPOINT usr/bin/mongod
```